Modelio Class diagram doesn't propagate properties and methods;
In Modelio I've created a class 'person', with 'Name' and 'Age' as properties. Then I create a class called 'employee' that inherites from the class 'person' using a 'Generalization (inheritance link)', like so;

But to my surprise non of the properties are actually inherited.
I expect the employee class to automaticially have the all properties from the parent object, like 'Name' and 'Age'. That's the whole point of inheritance...
So my questions;

Should this automatically be filled with items from the parent class?
If not, is there any tool like Modelio that can do that?

